# i am using javascript drag and drop events in angular 6 . but facing issue in ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

i want to drag and drop element from left div to right divs (1 and 2) . but i dont want to move element from left div it should copy from left div and paste on right div because i want to drag and drop element from left div to other divs also. i tried  **ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";** but it is not working properly . what to do please help? i am working in an angular application. also i should copy and paste from left main div but element should swap places between div 1 and 2 i am attaching stackblitz link for example please help.

image should copy and dropped from main left div to right div 1 and 2. but image should move and dropped between right div 1 and 2

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ftmtye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

your drop method should look something like below:

```
  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if (ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed === 'move') {
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if (ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed === 'copy') {
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode());
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is not working properly when i try to drag and drop from right div 1 to right div 2. its not dragging/moving.its not moving image from right div 1 to right div 2. clone from left div to right works fine. but not moving image from right div 1 to right div 2 .drag events doesn't copied to new place i think thats why? how to do this

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ftmtye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html   updated with your code. now only issue left is moving item from right div 1 to right div 2.

Comment: For Left div, we have (dragstart)="drag($event)" in which we are setting effect allowed to copy. 
But for Div 1 and Div 2, we are not doing that. By default effect allowed is 'all'. So, its not going into either of the if conditions. You might have to decide what should be the default behavior and handle it accordingly. 
If copy is default, then remove if condition specific to copy. you should have a catch all or default option. Hope my explanation helps.